# How to start SQL Server Agent?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I checked the SQLAGENT.out

`- ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15247, User does not have permission to do this action [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, EXECUTE autorisation has been refused on the object 'sp_sqlagent_has_server_access', database 'msdb', schéma 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229,EXECUTE autorisation has been refused on the object 'sp_sqlagent_get_startup_info', database 'msdb', schéma 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] 
 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, UPDATE autorisation has been refused on the object 'sysalerts', database 'msdb', schéma 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DumpAndCheckServerVersion)
 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, INSERT autorisation has been refused on the object 'syssessions', database 'msdb', schéma 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] 
 - ! [000] Error while creating a new session
 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normal mode)`

My user is in the administrator group. I tried to perform the same action while 'executing as administrator' same thing happened. I tried as NT AUTHORITY\System, same thing happened. I'm out of ideas now.

These are my Sql informations :

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  11.0.2100.60

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML                         3.0 5.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer             9.11.9600.17207

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18444

Système d'exploitation  6.1.7601

Am I missing anything? I've been told that my user has all rights on the PC so any idea why this is happening?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found my problem. SQL Server Agent is not included in Express edition and if I run this thing 

`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion, 
SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS ProductLevel, 
SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition`

I get `10.0.2531.0    SP1      Express Edition (64-bit)`

So I guess I'm not allowed to run it.

Oh well thanks anyway.